# Get JSONPto work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to access data from a php server with a cross domain support. So when i try $.ajax with dataType : 'jsonp' i have an error in console: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token The file is interpret as a javascript file an the request fail. Have you an idea for get data whithout this error.

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'http://domaine.com/json.php',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType : 'jsonp',
    success : function(data){
        console.log(data);
        // no enter in this callback
    },
    complete: function(data1, data2, data3){
        // no data from file.js
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First make sure that your PHP script supports JSONP. Identify the query string parameter that needs to be passed so that the script returns JSONP. Then test it in your browser by directly entering the following address in your address bar:

```
http://domain.com/json.php?callback=abc
```

You should see something along the lines of:

```
abc({ ... some JSON here ... })
```

You might need to adjust the `callback` name parameter if your PHP script expects a different one. This could be the case if you see the following output (`{ ... some JSON here ... }` without being wrapped in your javascript function)

And once you have ensured that you have a valid PHP script that returns JSONP you could consume it:

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'http://domain.com/json.php',
    jsonp: 'callback',
    dataType : 'jsonp',
    success : function(data){
        console.log(data);
        // no enter in this callback
    },
    complete: function(data1, data2, data3){
        // no data from file.js
    }
});
```

Things to notice:

1. I have specified the callback using the `jsonp: 'callback'` parameter
2. I have gotten rid of the `contentType: 'application/json'` parameter because jQuery's implementation of JSONP uses `script` tags which doesn't allow you to set any request headers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `?callback=?` to the request so that the proper callback is evaluated.  It may not be called `callback`, though.  You need to find out what it is called from the domain.

If the domain (and browser) supports [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/), you don't even need to use JSONP.  You can use a normal request.

Comment: jQuery should add `callback=?` automatically for JSONP requests

Comment: `If the domain supports CORS`. I would add and `if the browser supports CORS` because it's not enough only for the domain to support it.